# Error in a Simple Socket program

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I am not able to send the data on the second instance. The server just waits infinitely for client data
Here is my sample server code snippet:

```
ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(6789);
    Socket soc = serv.accept();
    System.out.println("waiting for client's input");       
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
    String indata=in.readLine();
    System.out.println("The client says: "+indata+"\n Send them some data: ");
    String datum="demodata";        
    out.writeBytes(datum);
    System.out.println("Data sent");
```

Sample Client:

```
ocket soc = new Socket("localhost",6789);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());     
    System.out.println("Connected to: "+soc.getLocalAddress() +"\nEnter data to be sent: ");        
    String outdata = br.readLine(); //take input    
    out.writeBytes(outdata); // send 
    String indata=in.readLine(); //read
    System.out.println("Data Sent! Now reading data from server "+indata)
```

Please tell me my problem! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is quite simple. You want to exchange lines of text between server and client.

The correct part is on the server side:

```
String indata=in.readLine();
```

The wrong part is on the client side:

```
out.writeBytes(outdata); // send
```

I haven't tested the code, but it seems you are just sending some data and your server side waits for `\n` (newline escape sequence) to appear.

**Option 1:**
Construct a `PrintWriter` and call the corresponding `println` method.

**Option 2:**
Append a newline (`\n`) manually.

Afterwards, `readLine` on the server side will recognize the line terminated by `\n` and will proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot to flush output stream.

Add the line: `out.flush()` just after `out.writeBytes()` on both server and client sides.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is not sending a newline character in the output it is writing. And your server is expecting this newline, implicitly, by calling `readLine` on BufferedReader (which expects a terminating newline character in the data it reads via that method). Add the following in both your client and server code, after calling `out.writeBytes()`:

```
out.newLine();
out.flush();
```

Alternatively, you can use PrintWriter's instead and just utilize its `println` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code. See if it works for you. You can stop the server code with Ctrl-C and the client will wait for the server to reappear.

Also, you can stop the server and it will wait for the client to reappear.
The main method has syntax

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketIPC{
    public PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    Socket socket = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    StringBuffer sb;
    int port;

    public SocketIPC(int port) throws Exception{
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void send(String msg){
        sb.append(msg+"\n");
    }

    public void flush(){
        out.write(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        out.flush();
    }

    public String recv() throws Exception{
            return in.readLine();
    }

    public void setIO() throws Exception{
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuffer();
    }

    public void serverLoop() throws Exception{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            setIO();

            int count = 0;
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            while(true){
                count += 1;
                for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
                    send("+");
                send(String.format(".%d", count));
                flush();
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                String msg = recv();
                if (msg!=null)
                    System.out.println(msg);
                else
                    break;// socket connection is broken
            }
            }
    }

    public void clientLoop() throws Exception{
        while(true){
            while(socket==null){
                try{
                    socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Waiting for server.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
                }
            setIO();

            System.out.println("Connected.");
            while(true){
                String msg = recv();
                if (msg==null){
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                    break;
                }
                if (msg.charAt(0)=='.'){
                    int idx = Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(1));
                        System.out.println(idx);
                    send(Integer.toString(idx));
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length != 1){
            System.out.println("Server invocation: java test.SocketIPC s");
            System.out.println("Client invocation: java test.SocketIPC c");
        }

        int port = 32000;
        try{
            SocketIPC fip = new SocketIPC(port);
            if (args[0].equals("s")){
                System.out.println("Server started");
                fip.serverLoop();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Client started");
                fip.clientLoop();
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```